# jQuery :not selector is not applied

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an `<i>` element having a class `comment-action edit-comment`.

I am listening on `click` event on this element and once triggered I add additional class `disabled` to all these `<i>`s:

```
$('.comment-action.edit-comment').on('click', function(){
    this.addClass('disabled');
    // another logic ...
});
```

This leads to small change in the event listener, thus to be

```
$('.comment-action.edit-comment:not(.disabled)').on('click', function(){ /* ... */ });
```

Unfortunately it looks like the `:not()` selector is ignored completely as clicking on `<i>` having also class `disabled` still triggers the event listener.

I also tried *more readable* form:

```
$('.comment-action.edit-comment').not('.disabled').on('click', function(){ /* ... */ });
```

with the very same result (as I also expected).

Any idea where the catch is?

Comment: $('.comment-action.edit-comment') .? means using two different class or what.? else create jsfiddle for more help coz it seems like selector is incorrect

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara Don't answer if you do not understand the basics... jQuery selector `$('.comment-action.edit-comment')` will select all HTML elements having `class="comment-action edit-comment"`... Respectively `$('.comment-action.edit-comment:not(.disabled)')` **should not** select element having `class="comment-action edit-comment disabled"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are setting your events, you are setting them directly on every element that matches. Everything with the comment-action and edit-comment class has the event on it when the page is loaded. Even when you add :not(.disabled), since those elements don't have the disabled class when the page loads, it matches.

You can use event delegation to set up an event on a parent element, but only runs if the target matches what you are looking for.

```
$(document).on('click', '.comment-action.edit-comment:not(.disabled)', function() { 
    //... 
});
```

Creating a delegate event handler has the advantage of only setting up 1 listener, instead of a listener for each element that matches your selector.

Comment: Yes, here is the relevant link regarding [$().on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). You'll also see it refered to as events "bubbling up".

Answer (score 2):

**Reason:**

The problem with

```
$('.comment-action.edit-comment:not(.disabled)')
```

and

```
$('.comment-action.edit-comment').not('.disabled')
```

is that it check if the selector is not having the class `disabled` at the time of binding event, and not when the event is occurred.

**Solution:**

You can check if the target element have `disabled` class in event handler. If the clicked element have class, you can use `return false` at the beginning of the event handler. So that the handler code is not executed.

```
$('.comment-action.edit-comment').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
        return false;
    }

    /* Code Here */
});
```